# A coin is tossed until we see exactly k heads. Let X be the random variable corresponding to the number of tosses. What is E(X)? What is var(X)?

Tags: statistics, random-variables

For this question I know this seems like a geometric random variable function but I don't know how to compute $E(X)$ from knowing nothing else. The hint that we are given is Let $Y= X1+X2+. . .+Xk$
where $Xi$ is the number of extra coin tosses required after the $(i − 1)^{th}$ head is observed until the ith head is observed.

Comment: You're right that this has to do with geometric random variables.

Answer (score 1):

Further hint:

$$X = \sum_{i=1}^k X_i$$

$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{i=1}^k \mathbb{E}[X_i]$$

$$Var[X] = \sum_{i=1}^k Var[X_i]$$

since $X_i$ are i.i.d.

Note: There is a special name to the distribution of $X_i$ describing number of trials until the first success.